# Android: Rotation Vector Sensor - Detect rotation to right or left

Tags: java, android, vector, rotation, sensors

I'm currently programming a Application which needs to detect the **Y** of the Phone. I mean the **Y-Axis**. See the image below:

[image]

I want to take pictures at every 30 degrees. The user need to rotate his/her phone to left (-90°) (so the app has captured now 3 pictures. 90°/ 30° = 3 pictures) and at least the user need to rotate his/her phone to right (+90°) (now the app has captured totally 6 pictures (a panorama of 180° in total. 6*30° = 180°)).

That's it. How i can do that? There is another example as an image below:

[image: Detail]

**Note:** The Phone doesn't change the position. The Phone is always at the red point. Only rotations.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I think this quesiton is too broad to be answered here. This might help you though: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html.

Comment: Hey pablochan thanks for the quick answer. I already know the site, but I still have problems.

Comment: Could you describe the exact problems that you're having? Are you getting an error? Is something working not as expected? Your question is more likely to be answered if you provide more details

Comment: Hmm.. how should I describe that. I had multiple codes for that but they all doesn't work. I just want to take pictures with my android app every 30° (rotation to right/left --- like https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEa5E.jpg the Y-Axis every 30 degrees). But I failed. So now I'm here for help. I worked with the SensorManager from Android and the Rotation Vector Sensor (built-in) but I failed.